# My Basic jsf tags are not rendering in to html tags

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2

Im a Totally new in Java and JSF. I'm using eclipse Indigo and Tomcat 6.0.3 and JSF 2.0.

When i run the Page in Browser, I just get an empty page, but i could the elements in firebug that it is still in JSF tags itself. It is not rendering in html..

This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>ContactFormJSF</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>pages/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>*.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

This is my Basic JSF content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Add New User Form</title>
</h:head>
    <h:body>
        <f:view>
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid border="1" columns="3">
                <h:outputText value="Name"></h:outputText>
                <h:inputText value="#{userBean.name}" required="true"></h:inputText>
                <h:outputText value="D.O.B"></h:outputText>
                <h:inputText id="DOB" value="#{userBean.dob}" required="true"> </h:inputText>
                <h:outputText value="Age"></h:outputText>
                <h:inputText id="age" value="#{userBean.age}" required="true"> </h:inputText>
                <h:commandButton action="#{userBean.addUser}" value="Submit"></h:commandButton>
                <input type="reset"/>
                <h:commandButton action="#{userBean.reset}" value="Reset"> </h:commandButton>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
        </f:view>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Iam Struggling for this for a week, I have tried out many things noted down in stackoverflow..

The URL iam using is localhost:8080/ContactFormJSF/
I could see the HTML tags which is added above in the Browser but not the jsf tags..

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the `FacesServlet` mapping in your `web.xml` doesn't cover the `.xhtml` files, so you should add the proper mapping to the configuration file:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In other side, you should retreive this to let the JSF controller recognize the `.xhtml` files in your project:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>*.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Iam getting error if i add the Faces Servet and url-pattern as *.xhtml                                                                ava.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
 javax.faces.application.Application.getResourceHandler(Application.java:254)
 javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:640

Comment: Is the JSF implementation in the classpath present ?

Comment: Are you implementing the proper version ?
Can you put the exception's details ?

Comment: I assume that you removed `/pages` from `<welcome-file>` tag. Also, you can remove the unnecessary mapping from your `web.xml` like `*.faces` & `/faces/*`, sometimes they cause troubles, one mapping is sufficient.

Comment: Including <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern> in web.xml file accepts *.xhtml files, so there is no need to add another mapping for that.